# How to fetch comma separated values from mentioned string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

I want to fetch comma separated IDs and types from below string.

I tried through split but that requires multiple split to fetch desired result.

Please suggest an efficient way to fetch desired output like like `1234,4321` using js/jquery.

```
var tempString=
'[{"id":"1234","desc":"description","status":"activated","type":"type","name":"NAME"},
  {"id":"4321","desc":"description1","status":"inactivated","type":"type","name":"NAME1"}]';
```

Comment: What's the desired result ?

Comment: comma separed Ids like 1234,4321

Comment: Naming your initial array "tempString" is a little confusing in my opinion.

Comment: @SLaks:now it is..:)..@dystroy:its just for question purpose

Comment: Where do you even get such a string from? You should change your code to either get a proper array or JSON string.

Comment: @Sandy I fixed the JSON in your question, please check this is really what you want to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `"1234,4321"`, you can do

```
var ids = tempString.map(function(v){return v.id}).join(',');
```

If you want to be compatible with IE8, then you can do

```
var ids = $.map(tempString, function(v){return v.id}).join(',');
```

**Following question edit :**

If `tempString` isn't an array but really a JSON string, then you'd do

```
var ids = $.map(JSON.parse(tempString), function(v){return v.id}).join(',');
```

Comment: Thanks for clean,quick and neat solution.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, that's not a String in your example. Some quotation marks went missing.

At any rate, look into @dystroy's answer, but I think you are dealing with JSON objects, and you should probably be useing a json parser (or even javascripts raw eval if you must) and then fetch your components as object properties and arrays.

Check out [jquery's parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use any Javascript parser api for JSON to decode the given string into keys and subsequent values.  As mentioned by 'Miquel', jQuery has one

Answer (score 0):

first off what you have above isn't a string, it is an array of objects.

BUT

if it were a string (like so )

```
var tempString = '[{"id":"1234","desc":"description","status":"activated","type":"type","name":"NAME"}]
```

[{"id":"4321","desc":"description1","status":"inactivated","type":"type","name":"NAME1"}]';

Then you would want to use something like .match();
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

var IDs = tempString.match(/([0-9]+)/gi);